# aws s3 cp emr stdout.gz file as txt encoding issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, encoding, gzip, aws-cli

I use `aws s3 cp s3://source_bucket/stdout.gz s3://target_bucket/stdout.txt` in linux to copy this log file to another s3 location. and if I download the file to my windows folder, the content format of this txt file looks exactly as you would see when you view the stdout in the emr step interface. and I simply opened it with the windows native notepad application

but when I sync this file to my windows directory using the command in windows cmd: `aws s3 sync s3://target_bucket/stdout.txt c://myfolder/stdout.txt` and when open it with notepad again, I see all messed up un-readable chars.

I tried with   `--content-encoding gzip and --content-type text/plain` option, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The `aws s3 cp` command uses the S3 API behind the scenes, which supports transparent decompression for a number of common compression types like gzip, bzip2, zip etc. This is intended to facilitate the downloading of compressed files without having to manually decompress them first.

The `aws s3 sync` command differs from copy in that it operates on directories and tries not to be helpful by decompressing the file.  I would suggest trying to sync the whole directory or target the specific file in the directory as such `aws s3 sync s3://target_bucket c:\myfolder\target --include 'stdout.txt'`.

Comment: Hi Christian, can you point to a source that documents this transparent decompression capability?

Comment: @jarmod Are you using a Snowball Edge?  I am not able to reproduce this in my test environment using plain S3.

Comment: I'm confused by your comment. No, I'm not using Snowball Edge or even regular S3. I'm asking about documented behavior. What are you *not* able to repro in your test environment? As it happens, I did test this with regular S3, and saw zero attempt by S3 to automatically decompress gzip files when either downloading them (using aws s3 cp) or copy to another bucket (again using aws s3 cp).

Comment: Sorry @jarmod, I meant that question for dozel.  I am not able to repro either... there is some extra features with Snowball Edge that have auto de/compression functionality.